# Create an Apache SetEnv variable with the subdomain name in case of wildcard

Tags: apache, subdomain, wildcard, setenv

I have a website that is basically set up as this:
client_name.website.com

...where clientname is actually a wildcard. For every new customer, I create a subdomain basically.

I need to automatically get the client name info directly from Apache. For example, if one comes throught:
client1.website.com
...I would like to have apache do a 
SetEnv CLIENT_NAME client1
for me.

Since I work with wildcard, it would be nice if this SetEnv would be done dynamically. Really pratical for great amounts of customers.

How would you achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
SetEnvIf Host "^([^\.]*)\.website\.com$" CLIENT_NAME=$1
```

Hopefully that helps.