# Setting the subdomain as a variable in apache config to be used in the same config file:

Tags: apache, environment-variables, subdomain, wildcard

1. How to define dynamically the subdomain of wildcard address as a variable in apache configuration file ?
2. How can I call the enviroment variable in configuration file of apache ? 
   This option here doen't work:
   [Create an Apache SetEnv variable with the subdomain name in case of wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032810/create-an-apache-setenv-variable-with-the-subdomain-name-in-case-of-wildcard#new-answer)
   It seems it doesn't work.

I've tried:

setting the enviroment virable:

- SetEnv SUBDOMAIN subdomainx
- SetEnvIf Host "^([^.]*).domainx.tldx$" SUBDOMAIN=$1
- SetEnvIf Host "^([^.]*).domainx.tldx$" SUBDOMAIN=specificsubdomainx
- Define SUBDOMAIN %-3

retrieving the variable in the same config file:

- ${SUBDOMAIN}
- %{SUBDOMAIN}
- SUBDOMAIN

Please help, Its freaking me out. Thanks

Comment: So, now I understand that environment variables to be used in apache config should be exported & defined in "envvars" file. But there apache modules do not work.
I tried: 
`
export SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^" subdomainx=subdomainx
`
still not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SetEnvIf Host "^([^.]*).domainx.tldx$" SUBDOMAIN=$1
```

looks ok (provided the domain you're using it on is *.domainx.tldx)

But you have to reference the variable like this:

```
%{ENV:SUBDOMAIN}
```

Comment: I have the exact same thing but it's not working , still printing %{ENV:SUBDOMAIN}

Comment: The dots (".") in the domain name shall be escaped like:
`"^([^.]*)\.domainx\.tldx$"`